# How to make RealityKit entity passthrough?

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit, visionos

[image: window material]

How to make a material that acts as a window/glass with opacity like in the image? The goal is to have two entity that overlap each other: a wall and a window entity, and we can see through the window entity.

I have tried playing around with the OpacityComponent and with the PhysicallyBasedMaterial.Blending, but without luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a transparent material in RealityKit using either of the following materials:

- [PhysicallyBasedMaterial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/physicallybasedmaterial)
- [CustomMaterial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/custommaterial)
- [SimpleMaterial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/simplematerial)
- [UnlitMaterial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/unlitmaterial)

##### PhysicallyBasedMaterial & CustomMaterial

Both PhysicallyBasedMaterial and CustomMaterial have a [Blending](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/physicallybasedmaterial/blending-swift.property) property as you mention, which you can set like this:

```
var material = PhysicallyBasedMaterial() // or CustomMaterial
material.blending = .transparent(opacity: .init(floatLiteral: 0.5))
```

##### SimpleMaterial & UnlitMaterial

With UnlitMaterial and SimpleMaterial you can simply set a color with alpha component, like so:

```
let transparentColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

let unlit = UnlitMaterial(color: transparentColor)

var simple = SimpleMaterial()
simple.color.tint = transparentColor
```

Now any of these materials can be applied to your window entity and you should be able to see through the entity. Adjust alpha or blending property to get the transparency you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, will try it!
And is there any solution to see through the window which occludes with a wall which is not transparent? So that the part of the wall which is occluded with the window also becomes transparent? I played around with ModelSortGroup but without luck.

Comment: If I understand your question about occlusion correctly, you want to be able to see through the wall where the window is, without modifying the mesh of the wall? You could try to position a vertical plane mesh directly behind the window and apply occlusion material to the plane, as this material will prevent content behind it to render. 

But I don’t think this will look very good. To make it look more like the photo you uploaded, I recommend looking into ways to modify the wall mesh to cut out space for the window instead.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I want! I will try manipulating the mesh itself, but actually, I could somehow solve it just by using a window with passthrough material (as you can also see in the question's image). But the issue was that sometimes it works (I can see through it), and sometimes it does not (I cannot see through it).
Isn't it connected with how the entities are rendered? I mean that if the window is rendered after the wall, then it is passthrough. This is an API connected with that, but I had no luck with it:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/modelsortgroup